# How to scroll to bottom modal after request and DOM update?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an online chat widget. When opening a specific chat, I want to automatically scroll the widget down to the last message. I am using an `async` function, but it didn't work for me.

```js
await axios.post('/', {
  id: id
}).then((response) => {
  this.messages = response.data;
});

console.log($('#SomeName .messages').height()); // here the height is zero, but it should be different, much more

$('#SomeName').animate({
  scrollTop: $('#SomeName .messages').height()
}, 200);
```

After loading the chat messages, I get `0` height for the widget, so auto scrolling doesn't work. How do I wait for the DOM to fully update and get the real height of the element?

I also understand that the use of the `await` clause in the described case is redundant, since there is a `.then()` construction, but I have not seen other options. It doesn't work anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fire the animation after vue.js has updated the DOM. 
To do that you can use [Vue.nextTick()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick)

```js
axios
  .post('/', {id: id})
  .then(response => {
    this.messages = response.data;

    // DOM not updated yet: That's why you are getting 0 as height
    Vue.nextTick(() => {
      // DOM updated: Fire your animation here
      $('#SomeName').animate({scrollTop: $('#SomeName .messages').height()}, 200);
    });
  });
```

NOTE: *I know that depends of your project structure, but just in case, don't forget to do `import Vue from 'vue'` if necessary*

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I wanted!